# Hosting Pritunl VPN on aws load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn, pritunl

I am trying to host Pritunl VPN on EC2 instance which is in private subnet(no public IP). The idea is to host it via

**1) Application Load Balancer**

The issue with this approach is, Pritunl uses UDP protocol for connection but ALB doesn't support UDP.

**2) Network Load Balance**

I created NLB with listeners for TCP 80 and 443 ports. Security groups are allowing access to these ports from everywhere(just for test). But when I try to use URL, hosted using route53 with NLB as an alias, it gives me 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'.

I tried this whole setup using EC2 on public IP address and everything works fine.

Can someone tell me what's the best approach to handle this?

Comment: Is it a typo about TCP listeners for NLB? Shouldn't it be UDP instead?

Comment: @anemyte yah I tried to add UDP listener as well. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Target group of target type ALB and route traffic from port 80 to 443 and route traffic of port 443 to a Target group of target type Instance and add the Pritunl instance to it **Both target groups should use port 443 as target port, as the pritunl by default runs on port 443.**.
From the NLB create Listeners TCP 80 and TCP 443 and route them to the above TG.

[NLB LISTNERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1jR1.png)

[Target groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMoYj.png)

Comment: What about the ports for openvpn/wireguard?